# Building json object with nested arrays in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a json structure and I need to build it dynamically using .net the example provided is:

```
   '{"payload":{"message" : <message>, "badge" : <badge>}[, "filter" : {"deviceID" :           <deviceID criteria>,"<param1>" : <criteria>, ...}][, "schedule": {"scheduledTime":  >   <scheduled_time>, "useTimeZone": <use_time_zone>}]}'
```

So far I have been able to get only the first part of the json completed using:

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Using writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer.WritePropertyName("payload")
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer.WritePropertyName("message")
            writer.WriteValue("Hello World!")
            writer.WritePropertyName("badge")
            writer.WriteValue(7)
            writer.WriteEnd()
            End Using
```

this gives me:

```
  {
  "payload": {
  "message": "Hello World!",
  "badge": 7
}
```

And then if I try to introduce the array using writer.WriteStartArray() I get errors,  how do I do this correctly?

I have now got to the bottom of the correct way to construct the json at least in jquery!  The syntax is;

```
var T = 'This is a Test!';
var D = '1';
return {"message": T , "badge": D };
```

[image: The request payload]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, JSon output from your current code missing single closing curly bracket. I'm not sure, but that could be the cause of error when you add `writer.WriteStartArray()`. Try to fix missing closing curly bracket by calling `WriteEndObject` :

```
writer.WriteValue("Hello World!")
writer.WritePropertyName("badge")
writer.WriteValue(7)
writer.WriteEndObject()
writer.WriteEndObject()
End Using
```

**UPDATE :**

I think square bracket in the specification doesn't mean an array. I somehow believe it means that part inside the square bracket is optional property.

```
[, "filter" : {"deviceID..."}]
```

notice a comma at the beginning of square bracket content, it indicates that `filter` is another property you can append after two mandatory properties `message` and `badge`.

Comment: If I add WriteEndObject it closes the json and does not allow any additional json to be written as in the example in my post.

Comment: add any additional json before `WriteEndObject`. And check my update, I believe you don't meant to add any array

Comment: Thanks that makes sense I will attempt to complete the json and poast it to the site and see if it is OK.  I will get back and let you know.